# ASP.NET MVC: Retrieving Information Stored in Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

I have a view in my site that displays all controller and its action methods of my application:
Action Method:

```
public ActionResult GetAllController()
{
    var controllers = typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(typeof (IController).IsAssignableFrom);
    return View(controllers.ToList());
}
```

View:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            <li>
                @item.Name
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var action in item.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Where(method => typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType)))
                    {
                        <li>action.Name</li>
                    }
                </ul>

            </li>
    }

</ul>
```

It works like a charm:

```
HomeController
     Index
     About
MainController
     Index
     Create
     Edit
     Delete
...
```

Now I want to display another name for controllers and the action methods. for doing that I have created a custom attribute:

```
public class DisplayNameAttribute : FilterAttribute
{
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DisplayNameAttribute(string title)
        {
            this.Title = title;
        }

}
```

So in this case I just set that attribute for each of controllers or action methods like this:

```
[DisplayName("Latest News")]
public ActionResult News()
{
     return View();
}
```

In this case I created an extension method for using inside views:

```
public static string DisplayAttribute<T>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, string>> value)
        {
            var memberExpression = value.Body as MemberExpression;
            var attr = memberExpression.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true);
            return ((DisplayNameAttribute)attr[0]).Title;
        }
```

So inside view I'm using this way for displaying the title of action method or controller:

```
@item.DisplayAttribute(p => p.Name)
```

But when I run application I'll get this error:

```
{"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}
```

That throws from this line of code:

```
return ((DisplayNameAttribute)attr[0]).Title;
```

Any idea?

Comment: what does the rendered html look like? This might be available front end instead?

Comment: pretty simple. you are trying to reference an index in an array that does not exist i.e attr.Length would be 0 but you are asking to get the first item in the attr array - there is no first item. ALWAYS validate the object/array before accessing it.

Comment: Is it a typo that you use `ControllerName` instead of `DisplayName` on the action? If not, that's probably your issue.

Comment: Also, you should probably derive your attribute from `Attribute` instead of `FilterAttribute`, so that MVC doesn't add it to the filter pipeline.

Comment: @jbutler483 As I mentioned the result is this error: `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: @Alxandr Sorry I updated my question :)

Comment: @Alxandr yes you're right. I try Attribute too, But I got same error.

Comment: I would put a breakpoint in that [0] index accessor and see what happens when you run. I'd guess you've got a method without this attribute being set somewhere. Perhaps try using a count > 0 clause before it.

Comment: Check your namespaces.  `System.ComponentModel` defines a `DisplayNameAttribute` class as well.  I'm guessing either your attributes are coming from that namespace, or your extension method is using that namespace.  If you are using Visual Studio you can hover your mouse over the type in your code and it should tell you the namespace.

Comment: @Dan-o it comes from true namespace. I also changed its name. But I got same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this more closely, I can see that there are multiple problems with your code. Though, the main problem is the fact that you try to read attributes of a framework property, and expect it to contain your own defined attributes (which, as far as I know isn't even possible).

So, let's analyze the call `@item.DisplayAttribute(p => p.Name)`. I assume here, that `item` refers to the same `item` in your previous razor code, which would mean it has a type of `MethodInfo` (from `System.Reflection`). And you call your method `DisplayAttribute` with the following expressions:

```
DisplayAttribute<MethodInfo>(MethodInfo item, Expression<Func<MethodInfo, string>> mi => mi.Name);
```

Bear in mind that this isn't actually a valid call in C#, but I've added the type information to easier show what is going on.

Now, the `MemberExpression` you acquire inside the `DisplayAttribute` method, is not the controller method at all, it's the property `string MethodInfo.Name {get;}`. This is a framework property (defined in mscorlib as far as I know), and obviously does not have your defined property.

What you probably wanted to do, was something akin to this instead:

```
public static string GetAttributedName(this ICustomAttributeProvider attributeProvider) {
    return attributeProvider.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Select(a => a.Title).FirstOrDefault() ?? "No title found";
}
```

The bit at the end with `"No title found"` is just to make it simpler to find where the problem lies (if this does not work). If you want it to throw an exception if there is no attribute, simply replace `FirstOrDefault` with `First`, and remove the part after the method call.

#### [Edit]

Forgot to mention: usage would be like this: `@item.GetAttributedName()`

#### [Edit 2]

I made some improvements, you can see a basically working sample here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7H5ITo.

Answer (score 1):

If the element action or controller isn't decorated with the `DisplayName` attribute it is pretty normal that you will get an IndexOutOfBounds exception. You might check for that in your extension method:

```
public static string DisplayAttribute<T>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, string>> value)
{
    var memberExpression = value.Body as MemberExpression;
    var attr = memberExpression.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true);
    if (attr.Length > 0)
    {
        return ((DisplayNameAttribute)attr[0]).Title;
    }

    // Return some default value
    return memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For another name of your action use Display(name="") attribute.
For example:

```
Display(name="View Action Name")
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
  return View();
}
```

to get action view name, in View modify it with

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @item.Name
            <ul>
                @foreach (var action in item.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Where(method => typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType)))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        <li>@action.CustomAttributes.SingleOrDefault(m => m.AttributeType.Name == "DisplayAttribute").NamedArguments.ElementAt(0).TypedValue</li>
                    }
                    catch(NullReferenceException){}



                }
            </ul>

        </li>
    }
```